# How to copy from one textarea to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have one page, with two `textarea` elements. How do I copy the text from one `textarea` to another?

```
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

So text area one is primarily where the data appears, I need to copy it to text area two during the onchange event.

Comment: Do `$("#two").val($("#one").val())` `onchange` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("#one, #two").on("change keyup", function(){
    $("textarea").not($(this)).val($(this).val());
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ccp1ph3d/)

The code will **synchronize** both `textareas`

Comment: This looks good, but the content in textarea one is just dumped by other function. I guess I need an event listener which will continously check for any changes in textarea one. thanks though!

Comment: @Thanos I didnt quite get what u mean. What u mean by the content is just dumped by other function?

Comment: User does not type manually into textarea one. Basically, I just need to check for changes in textarea one as soon as the page loads i.e some function running in background continuously and synchronize it with textarea two.

Answer (score 3):

Try This.

```js
function Copydata(){
  $("#two").val($("#one").val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="one" onkeyup=Copydata();></textarea>
<br/>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ccp1ph3d/4/)

```
$("#one").keyup(function(){
   $("#two").val($(this).val()) 
});
```

I Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on` - `input` too as below which responses for copy-paste too..

```
$("#one").on("input", function(){
    $("#two").val($(this).val());
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ccp1ph3d/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#one').on('keyup',function(){
    $('#two').val($(this).val());
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7drmmqow/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in JS, do the following:

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0qcejnm4/)

```js
function addEvent(el, name, func, bool) {
 if (el.addEventListener)
  el.addEventListener(name, func, bool);
 else if (el.attachEvent)
  el.attachEvent('on' + name, func);
 else el['on' + name] = func;
}

addEvent(one, 'keydown', function(e) {
 two.value = e.target.value;
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="one"></textarea>
<textarea id="two"></textarea>
```